# SwiftUI List .onDelete not working with filtered Core Data

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI application that is basically a master/detail app with data persisted in Core Data. The basic application works perfectly, however I have added a search bar (through `UIViewRepresentable`) and I had difficulty with the `ForEach.onDelete` functionality when the list is filtered.

If there is text in the search bar, I execute a fetch request on the Core Data entity which includes a predicate to search all of the text fields that I want to include. Then the filtered list is presented. Again, this works as expected. However, attempting to delete a record causes a crash. I believe this is because the `IndexSet` becomes invalid but I don't understand why that should be. At any rate, if I re-issue the call
to the filtered list in the `.onDelete` code (see the first `.onDelete` below), then the deletions work as expected. Even with this secondary search however, changes made on the detail screen are not shown when returning to the filtered list, though the changes are saved in Core Data.

While I guess it is not a big penalty to have to re-fetch, I am not confident that this is the proper procedure, and changes do not cause the List to update. Is there a way to use the `@FetchRequest` wrapper and dynamically provide a predicate? I have seen several SO posts on dynamic filters in Core Data but none of them have worked for me.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
struct ContentView: View {

@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
@FetchRequest(fetchRequest: Patient.getAllPatients()) var patients: FetchedResults<Patient>
@State private var searchTerm: String = ""
@State var myFilteredPatients = Patient.filterForSearchPatients(searchText: "")
//more properties


var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            MySearchBar(sText: $searchTerm)
            if !searchTerm.isEmpty {
                ForEach(Patient.filterForSearchPatients(searchText: searchTerm)) { patient in
                    NavigationLink(destination: EditPatient(patient: patient, photoStore: self.photoStore, myTextViews: MyTextViews())) {
                        //configure the cell etc.
                    }//NavigationLink
                }//for each
                    .onDelete { indexSet in
                    //This recreation was necessary:
                        self.myFilteredPatients = Patient.filterForSearchPatients(searchText: self.searchTerm)
                        let deleteItem = self.myFilteredPatients[indexSet.first!]
                        self.managedObjectContext.delete(deleteItem)
                        do {
                            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                        } catch {
                            print(error)//put up an alert here
                        }
                }
            } else {
                ForEach(self.patients) { patient in
                    NavigationLink(destination: EditPatient(patient: patient, photoStore: self.photoStore, myTextViews: MyTextViews())) {
                        //configure the cell etc
                    }//nav link
                }//for each
                    .onDelete { indexSet in
                        let deleteItem = self.patients[indexSet.first!] 
                        self.managedObjectContext.delete(deleteItem)
                        do {
                            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
                        } catch {
                            print(error)//put up and alert here
                        }
                }
            }//if else
        }//List

        //buttons and setup
    }//NavigationView
}//body
```

Xcode Version 11.2 (11B52)

Comment: Could you share with us a stack trace of the crash?

Comment: I think this has been fixed in Xcode 12.